# fgetc doesn't return last line of my file

Tags: c, fgetc

This is my first time writing C and I am trying to open a file and read its content. I am using fgetc to get the lines of my .txt file, but it is only returning the contents without the last line of my .txt file. How can I ensure fgetc returns the last line?

```
 FILE *fp = fopen("nums.txt", "r");
 if(fp)
 {
   int c = fgetc(fp); 
   while (c != EOF) 
   { 
     printf ("%c", c); 
     c = fgetc(fp);
   } 
 }
```

The expected result is:

```
12
13
14
```

But it returns to the console like this:

```
12
13
```

Comment: One issue: `c` needs to be an `int`, not a `char`: http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html

Comment: When c was an int, i also changed my printf statement to be `%d`, nothing printed to console. @Shawn

Comment: No, you should still use `%c` if you want to print a character and not its numeric value (Or better yet, since using `printf()` is massive overkill for displaying a single character, just use `putchar()` or the like).

Comment: @Shawn oh. even so, results are still the actual and expected results differ.

Comment: Comparing to EOF requires that c be an int.

Comment: @stark I’ve changed that, yet results still are incorrect as above

Comment: What happens if you add `fflush(stdout);` after your loop. I suspect your input file does not end with a newline and thus the last characters you're outputting to `stdout` are being buffered and not showing up.

Comment: Try running your program in a terminal, rather than using an IDE (CodeBlocks, no?) Dropping the last line of output is a known IDE bug.

Comment: The input file probably doesn't end with newline. And whatever you're using to view the output of the script doesn't show a line until a newline is printed.

Comment: Are you exiting from `main()` after this code? That should flush the output.

Comment: Switching out `%d` for `%c` and then not seeing any output does strongly support the broken ide theory because no newlines are being printed out by your program after that change.

Comment: update: I was using terminal to run the program, but turns out adding `fflush(stdout)` to the end of the loop works.

Comment: Or, to disable buffering entirely: `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setbuf(stdout, NULL);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) before loop to disable buffering.